# Get postId and postType of a template part in react component

Tags: block-editor

I am making a sidebar component, that is meant to be used on both post editor and template editor.
I know that templates in database stored as wp_template_part post type, however, I cannot get templates post_id or post_type from inside the template editor.
Any suggestion how this can be implemented?

```
const Component = ( {} ) => {

    const postId = useSelect( ( select ) =>
        select( 'core/editor' ).getCurrentPostId()
    );

    const postType = useSelect( ( select ) =>
        select( 'core/editor' ).getCurrentPostType()
    );
}
```

So this works on /wp-admin/post.php? pages
But i get undefined on /wp-admin/site-editor.php?postType=wp_template_part&postId=theme%2F%2Fheader

I expected it to actually return the wp_template_part as postType and it's ID, so I can save template specific postMeta from the sidebar, what is the correct approach?